# In WinUI 3 In ListView How to make single item selected and other all item unselected and unclickable?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winui-3, winui

In WinUI 3 application in ListView I want one item selected and it should accept key event and other all item should be unselected and unclickable or disable.
This is the code where I am trying to do this functionality,

```cs
internal static void MyListView(ListView view)
{
    view.SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.None; // tried to selection mode 'none'
    foreach (var i in view.Items)
    {
        ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)i; 
    }
}
```

here MyListView is method calling in separate class, there passing List view as a parameter.
I tried this using setting selection mode 'none' but for perticular index item How to make selectable.

*In UI I want to display Like This.*

*understand problem from below image.*
[image: screenshot related problem]

Updated:

- In my application having scenario list of items display.
- In that first to second last should be disabled and unclickable.
- Last item is should be already selected and in that I am already defined a key event. when we press space key that event hit and that last item color is changing.
- But if I click on the outside means other disable item my last item which is already selected it not accept any key event.
- This is happening because of disabling items. In WinUi-3 when ListView Item are disabled and if we click on that through mouse then it not accept any key event which I defined already (Last Item not accept event).
- So, I want functionality where List of items in that only last item should clickable and already click and It accept key event. if we click other disable item then also it should accept key event.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access each `ListViewItem` like this:

```cs
// In this case "view" is your ListView control.
foreach (object? item in view.Items)
{
    if (view.ContainerFromItem(item) is ListViewItem listViewItem)
    {
        listViewItem.IsEnabled = listViewItem.IsSelected;
    }
}
```

To answer your additional question from the comments, you can programmatically select and subscribe the last item to key events, then disable the other items like this:

```cs
// Select the last item.
int lastItemIndex = view.Items.Count - 1;

if (view.ContainerFromIndex(lastItemIndex) is ListViewItem lastListViewItem)
{
    lastListViewItem.IsSelected = true;
    lastListViewItem.KeyDown -= ListViewItem_KeyDown;
    lastListViewItem.KeyDown += ListViewItem_KeyDown;
}

// Disable all not-selected items.
foreach (object? item in ListViewControl.Items)
{
    if (view.ContainerFromItem(item) is ListViewItem listViewItem)
    {
        listViewItem.IsEnabled = listViewItem.IsSelected;
    }
}
```

```cs
private void ListViewItem_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how you want me to modify my first answer. Can you be more specific about it and the error you are getting?

Comment: To be clear, you want only the last item to be selected and the others disabled?

Comment: Updated my answer with an example to select the last item and disable the other items.

Comment: Your question says "unclickable" for not selected items. What are you trying to do clicking disabled items?

Comment: Last Item is selected, so that item accept key event but if we do disable this and click on disabled items, then that last selected item not accept any key event. I want to accept that event also..

Comment: By "if we do disable this", do you mean disabling the last item? It might be easier to understand your issue if you explain it in your original question.

Comment: check again my 'question'. I am updated my question. @Andrew

Comment: So, the last item (the only enabled item) should not accept key events until other items (disabled items) are clicked?

Comment: Not Like that, without clicking other items (disable item) last item can accept key event but when we click on the (disable item) then last item can not accepting key event and this is the issue. I want to last item accept key event. in both condition.

Comment: Since the last item is not disabled, it should work with key events. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Did you get to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, Sorry for late reply...!